# ZK MVVM Bind don't work

Tags: java, mvvm, zk

I have this simple ZK View and BindModel:

http://zkfiddle.org/sample/2pj12j3/1-ZK8-Bind-Don-t-Work

I am not able to load the form into the Java variables.

When the view is renderer, you can see the @bind code in the input components, and if you try to write in the inputs, you receive this error:

"Illegal Syntax for Set Operation"

Any suggest? I don't see the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find the problem.

BAD:

```
<textbox value="@bind('vm.username')" />
```

Good:

```
<textbox value="@bind(vm.username)" />
```